# Android PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues() crashes with class cast exception

Tags: android, casting, classcastexception, preference

I have a frustrating problem, I have created a custom preference for Android, using the support library.

```
public class CustomTimePreference extends DialogPreference {
    public int hour = 0;
    public int minute = 0;

    public CustomTimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public static int parseHour(String value) {
        try {
            String[] time = value.split(":");
            return (Integer.parseInt(time[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static int parseMinute(String value) {
        try {
            String[] time = value.split(":");
            return (Integer.parseInt(time[1]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static String timeToString(int h, int m) {
        return String.format("%02d", h) + ":" + String.format("%02d", m);
    }


    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return a.getString(index);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        String value;
        if (restoreValue) {
            if (defaultValue == null) value = getPersistedString("00:00");
            else value = getPersistedString(defaultValue.toString());
        } else {
            value = defaultValue.toString();
        }

        hour = parseHour(value);
        minute = parseMinute(value);
    }


    public void persistStringValue(String value) {
        persistString(value);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomTimePreferenceDialogFragmentCompat extends PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat implements DialogPreference.TargetFragment {
    TimePicker timePicker = null;

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView(Context context) {
        timePicker = new TimePicker(context);
        return (timePicker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
        CustomTimePreference pref = (CustomTimePreference) getPreference();
        timePicker.setCurrentHour(pref.hour);
        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(pref.minute);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if (positiveResult) {
            CustomTimePreference pref = (CustomTimePreference) getPreference();
            pref.hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
            pref.minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

            String value = CustomTimePreference.timeToString(pref.hour, pref.minute);
            if (pref.callChangeListener(value)) pref.persistStringValue(value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Preference findPreference(CharSequence charSequence) {
        return getPreference();
    }
}
```

For completeness, the xml contained within the preferences.xml is:

```
<customcontrols.CustomTimePreference
            android:key="time_pace_preference"
            android:title="@string/title_time_pace_preference"
            android:defaultValue="@string/settings_default_pace"
            android:summary="Set some time"
            />
```

However, when I attempt to call

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(mContext, preferences, true);
```

I receive

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: customcontrols.CustomTimePreference cannot be cast to android.preference.Preference
```

Why is this happening? as CustomTimePreference extends DialogPreference which itself extends Preference, this should be fine?!

If I don't call the setDefaultValues() I am able to go into my settings fragment and view the custom control?

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it!?

Comment: `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(mContext, preferences, true);
` in this line, what is `preferences` variable? I do not see it anywhere in the code.

Comment: during the app initialization, the preferences int variable is passed in from the activity to my engine(which is a lib project) like so:

   `initialisedSDK = engine.initialise(this, this, R.xml.preferences);`

and this method signature is then:

    `public boolean initialise(Context mContext, engine callback, int preferences)` 

I should add prior to the new custom class this worked fine, I don't know if its something related to the support library?

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending `android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference` that will cause this crash.

If so, you can use `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager#setDefaultValues(android.content.Context, int, boolean)` instead.

Comment: @MahmoudHeretani I can't remember exactly but it looks like I'm saying "When you are using the support preferences classes you have to use the support `PreferenceManager`'s implementation of `setDefaultValues`, you cannot use the OS supplied `PreferenceManager`'s setDefaultValues. (Note that the packages are different for the two versions.)"